# WPF programmatically creating checkboxcolumn in listview

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

Hi all) I've got next problem - i should create some checkbox columns in listview. But it doesn't work and it displays such as True or False.

```
        private void CreateDataGridColumns()
    {
        var gridView = new GridView();
        PlanningDataGrid.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() {Header = "Тип мероприятия", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Key")}); // Создаем первый столбец
        var eventTypeList = GetEventTypesList();
        foreach (string eventType in eventTypeList)
        {
            gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() {Header = eventType, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"), CellTemplate = GenerateCellTemplate()});
        }
    }

    private DataTemplate GenerateCellTemplate()
    {
        var template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        factory.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding());
        template.VisualTree = factory;
        return template;
    }
```

Comment: what is happened if you remove the DisplayMemeberBinding declaration in your new GridViewColumn() {Header = eventType, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"), CellTemplate = GenerateCellTemplate()} expression?

Comment: All the same happens

Comment: do you have some errors in your Output window?

Comment: this: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=grid'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListView' (Name='PlanningDataGrid'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Comment: is there something related to the eventType or its content?

Comment: its a list, which gets from database like this:  return db.EVENTS_TYPE.Select(e => e.event_type.Trim()).ToList();

Comment: no I've meant is there something related to the eventType as an error in your output window? because there is no any problem with your code. The only thing, in my opinion, that can happened is the binding error. try to search in this direction.

Comment: Unfortuantelly, binding is OK. When i generate model, i set bool as false and it displays, if i change value to true, it displays too. i create other topic,  where i described my problem fully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129861/wpf-binding-listview-to-dictionarystring-dictionarystring-bool