# WPF binding listview to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I've got a problem, I have to take `List<string>` from database, create `Dictionary<Dictionary<string, bool>>` on it and fill `listview` with it.

Here is my code:

xaml:

```
    <ListView x:Name="PlanningDataGrid" 
              Grid.Row="0"
              Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding EventTypesCombinerCollection}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    </ListView>
```

model:

```
public class MainViewModel_Combiner : BindableBase // модель по событиям работы скважины
{
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> _eventTypesCombinerCollection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Именованный двумерный массив совмещения мероприятий. Совмещение определяется как EventTypesCombinerCollection["type1"]["type2"]
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> EventTypesCombinerCollection
    {
        get { return _eventTypesCombinerCollection; }
        set
        {
            _eventTypesCombinerCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EventTypesCombinerCollection");
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel_Combiner()
    {
        EventTypesCombinerCollection = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
        GenerateEventTypesCocllectionFrameFromDataBase();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заполняет двумерный словать типов мероприятий (абстракция для получения квадратной таблицы с одинаковыми заголовками строк и столбцов)
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateEventTypesCocllectionFrameFromDataBase()
    {
        var EventTypesList = GetEventTypesList();
        foreach (string eventTypeCombiner in EventTypesList)
        {
            Dictionary<string, bool> combiningItems = new Dictionary<string, bool>(); 
            foreach (string eventTypeCombining in EventTypesList)
            {
                combiningItems.Add(eventTypeCombining, false);
            }
            EventTypesCombinerCollection.Add(eventTypeCombiner, combiningItems);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Собирает список типов мероприятий из БД
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetEventTypesList()
    {
        using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
        {
            return db.EVENTS_TYPE.Select(e => e.event_type.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

and xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class Combiner : Window
{
    public Combiner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateDataGridColumns();
    }

    private void CreateDataGridColumns()
    {
        var gridView = new GridView();
        PlanningDataGrid.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Тип мероприятия", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Key") }); // Создаем первый столбец
        var eventTypeList = GetEventTypesList();
        foreach (string eventType in eventTypeList)
        {
            var listViewColumn = new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = eventType,
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"),
                Width = 30,
                CellTemplate = GenerateCellTemplate(eventType),
            };
            gridView.Columns.Add(listViewColumn);
        }
    }

    private DataTemplate GenerateCellTemplate(string eventType)
    {
        var template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        factory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"));
        template.VisualTree = factory;
        return template;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Собирает список типов мероприятий из БД
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetEventTypesList()
    {
        using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
        {
            return db.EVENTS_TYPE.Select(e => e.event_type.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: unfortunatelly it looks like this]

Have you know any way, how to fix this, or do smth new?

Comment: fix - make checkboxes instead "false"

Comment: ok, I'll try to check this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I,ve got a lot of troubles with this case

Comment: I have some progress: if delete line DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"), in xaml.cs file, then checkboxes will be displayed, but, of course, bindind will be loss.

Comment: try to create binding in the CreateDataGridColumns method and send it to the GenerateCellTemplate method, when you don't define the DisplayMemberBinding

Comment: I can't exactly understand, how to do this, explain, please, how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to StepUp and Ilan for helping. I just need to delete this row is code behind:

```
DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]"),
```

so, there is a solution:

```
    public partial class Combiner : Window
{
    public Combiner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateDataGridColumns();
    }

    private void CreateDataGridColumns()
    {
        var gridView = new GridView();
        PlanningDataGrid.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Тип мероприятия", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Key") }); // Создаем первый столбец
        var eventTypeList = GetEventTypesList();
        foreach (string eventType in eventTypeList)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            var listViewColumn = new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = eventType,
                Width = 30,
                CellTemplate = GenerateCellTemplate(eventType),
            };
            gridView.Columns.Add(listViewColumn);
        }
    }

    private DataTemplate GenerateCellTemplate(string eventType)
    {
        FrameworkElementFactory checkbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        checkbox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Value[" + eventType + "]") {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay});
        return new DataTemplate() {VisualTree = checkbox};
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Собирает список типов мероприятий из БД
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetEventTypesList()
    {
        using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
        {
            return db.EVENTS_TYPE.Select(e => e.event_type.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataTemplate` looks good. Try to write:

```
factory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(eventType));
```

The work example looks like the following code snippet:

```
 FrameworkElementFactory checkbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
 checkbox.Name = "aCheckBox";
 checkbox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("YourBoolProperty"));
 DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = checkbox };
```

**Update:**

To get a value from `Dictionary`, you should use the following syntax:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
string str = dictionary[1];
```

So your code should look like this:

```
factory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(dictionary[1]));
```

Comment: @ДмитрийРепин feel free to ask any question

Comment: I can not write: factory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(eventType)); because it's dictionary and eventType is a key

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have dictionaries with other types and I and paste it as you shown

Comment: @ДмитрийРепин just use Debugger to see how you should treat your `Dictionary<Dictionary<string, bool>>`